# mysql subquery row comparision logic

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have question on the subquery logic. For my understanding, sql always parse the subquery and then outler query. However, the example from official documents does not support that.

linke as blow from mysql official documents

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html

```
Here is another example, which again is impossible with a join 
because it involves aggregating for one of the tables. 
It finds all rows in table t1 containing a value that occurs twice in a given column:

SELECT * FROM t1 AS t
  WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id);
```

For my understanding, when sql parse the subquery, it will find the

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id)
```

return scalar based on the table. then when it compare with 2

it will either return all row in t1 or nothing since it is easy true or false question.

obvious it does not like what office documents discussion
. based on the official documents, it is more like checking row by row from t1 table, make comparsion with scalar 2 and keep looping the whole table until the end.

why the logic is like?  I have some difficulty to understand the logic.
Any future explaination will helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difficulty.

It depends all how many rows you get back, because it will check every row of t1 and compare if the table has 2 row with that value. lieke you can see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d70942c0321f9310c3b89dbc9435b418

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id)
```

reruns **1 value** (1 column 1 row) for example 3 which it compares to your 2 with =

As long as the subquery **only returns 1 Value** you can compare it with a singular value with =

For multiple Rows in the result set you need `IN`

LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM t1 AS t
  WHERE cis IN (SELECT t1.id FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id);
```

And of course you can compare to multiple columns(also here you need `ÌN` if you have multiple rows)

```
SELECT * FROM t1 AS t
  WHERE (2,2) = (SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(abc = 'test') FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id);
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood that. the one I get confused is the logic. (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id) should only return 1 column 1 rows right? in that case it could not achive the purpose to get the row existing 2 times.

Comment: no, count is the command that returns the one value independent of the number of rows you get without it,

Comment: if so, the subquery will only return 1 value depend on the table. so when compare 2 = the value, it will either return all t1 table or nothing, right?

Comment: 2 = 1 is boolean and will give you back 0 but that has nothing to do noth the subquery

Comment: I am not sure whether I follow you. if my understandinng correct, the logic is like following: subquery return 1 scalar value -- comparsion with 2---- outer query---if true return all table if false nothing return

Comment: 1.SEelct count gives back an integer 2. You compare 2 integers 3 result is a boolean with mysql represents as 0,. i can't explain it simpler that is already very basic

Comment: my confusion is not there. let us say the t have 3 row3 with 1, 2,2 as id. should i under the (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id) as whole, which will return 5 ?. or it is more row based logic? test t.id  =1 then t.id =2. then test t.id =2.

Comment: se if https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d70942c0321f9310c3b89dbc9435b418 helps, the count is for every row so  for 1 you have only 1 row so that would return 2 has two rows and would retunr in that case two as t1 has two rows with 2

Comment: thank you. I think I understood